# TypeError: $(...).tableToJSON is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Saudações
Ao clicar no Botão no meu projecto é apresentado o seguinte erro TypeError: $(...).tableToJSON is not a function, estou a usar o plugin tableToJSON

Código:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('#TermVenda').click(function(){
        var table =$('#products-table').tableToJSON(); 
        console.log(table);
        document.write(JSON.stringify(table));
        alert(JSON.stringify(table));
    });           
 });
```

Tabela HTML: `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Pagina do Cliente</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tabletojson.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="products-table" class="table table-hover table-bordered">            <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Produto</th>
                  <th>Preço </th>
                  <th>Qtd</th>
                  <th>Valor</th>
                  <th>Ações</th>
                </tr>
          </thead>
           <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Banana</td>
                <td>20</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>100</td>
                <td>x</td>
              </tr> 
              <tr>
                <td>Alho</td>
                <td>20</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>100</td>
                <td>x</td>
              </tr>

            </tbody> 
        </table>
    <button id="TermVenda">Converter</button> 
    </body>
</html>`

Comment: Você incuiu o jquery.tabletojson.js em sua página ?

Comment: Sim estão todos incluidos lá

Comment: Posivelmente você deve ter incluído o jquery.tablejson.js antes de incluir o  jquery.js. Altere a pergunta e poste o html com a inclusão dos js também.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possivelmente você não incluiu o **jquery** ou **jquery.tabletojson.js** em sua pagina. Abra o seu console developer pressionando F12 em seu navegador, e verifique se não há erros de carregamento dos JS.
Eu montei uma página de teste, conforme o link abaixo e funciona corretamente.

[TableToJson Pagina DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/q73Lwtgj/)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]